# How to open multiple chat boxes at the same time in hangouts.google.com?

Tags: google-hangouts

I haven't figured out how to control the number of chat boxes simultaneously open in hangouts.google.com. Sometimes I have more than one.

How can I control which and how many chat boxes are open simultaneously?

Answer (score -2):

Haha, I've stumbled over the same problem. The way this works is really really strange: If one of your chat boxes is TOO WIDE, it will "kick out" the others. So, just try to make an existing, open chat box narrowser, the other open ones might just magically appear then.

Strange UI, I know...